# Is there a way to add the navbar-toggle button in bootstrap as a fixed button on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add the navbar toggle button as given in the image
[image: Desired Button]
in my html page.

However, bootstrap gives us the option to create buttons such as this
[image: Current Button]

I do not want any normal button and specifically want the first image.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Meghna something like this ?? http://i.imgur.com/k3ndWus.jpg

Comment: Yes! Something like that which will permanently be there. The javascript for "on toggle code" has already been made so i just need the CSS or a way to use an existing bootstrap code. I can use the existing menu icon ( <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"> ) for now,  But if i can have the icon, I will modify the code accordingly.

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj Do you still have this issue or solved it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Still have this issue :/

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj Looks like I can fix it. Writing a HTML in JSBin for you. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Wow awesome!! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj Kindly check the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96608/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-meghna-natraj).

Comment: @PraveenKumar I did use your answer as an base to work on what i exactly wanted. Thank you soo much for that initial setup you've given me. i have added the css that i have used. I took the navbar-toggle and icon-bar class css from bootstrap and modified that itself. The output now looks like the image posted below!

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer has been split to 2 parts:
The initial code that was worked on. And final result that was used. 
Both can be used to create a menu icon that looks like the "navbar-toggle" button. But is always fixed on the screen!

**INITIAL TRIAL CODE**

- Makes use of `<span>` as in Bootstrap.
- Positioned on Top Right.
- CSS targeted (can change colour) and responsive.

```css
.ham-menu, .ham-menu span {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ham-menu {border: 2px solid #666; width: 32px; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px; }
.ham-menu .line {border: 3px solid #666; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; display: block; margin: 2px;}
.ham-menu .line.small {border-width: 2px;}

.ham-menu:hover {border-color: #99f;}
.ham-menu:hover span {border-color: #ccf;}
```

```html
<div class="ham-menu">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line small"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
</div>
<p>Hover and See</p>
```

**When the screen size is small (both toggle buttons are visible**

[image]

**When the screen size is large (the left toggle icon remains)**

[image]